# Create Checkbox with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkboxlist

I am trying to create a checkbox with javascript when a button is clicked.  I am really struggling, I have searched the net for help and this is the closest I've got but it does not work.

What have I done wrong?

```
<p>Click the buttons to create a Checkbox.</p>

<button onclick="addCheckBox()">Create a button</button>
<input id="check" name="checkBoxes">
<script>
function addCheckBox() {

    var ColorsAvailable = document.getElementById('checkBoxes');
    var check_value = new Array( )
    check_value[0] = "Yellow"
    check_value[1] = "Red"
    check_value[2] = "Green"


   for(var count in check_value)
    {
      var color=document.createElement("input");   
      color.value=(check_value[count] + '</br>');
      color.type="checkbox";
      color.id="color" + count;
      ColorsAvailable.appendChild(color);
   }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you add an element that has an `id` of `checkBoxes` and some semicolons `;` the code actually works.

```js
function addCheckBox() {

    var ColorsAvailable = document.getElementById('checkBoxes');
    var check_value = new Array();
    check_value[0] = "Yellow";
    check_value[1] = "Red";
    check_value[2] = "Green";

    var color, p, br;

   for(var count in check_value)
    {
      color=document.createElement("input");   
      color.value=(check_value[count] + '</br>');
      color.type="checkbox";
      color.id="color" + count;
      p =document.createElement("span");
      p.innerHTML = check_value[count] + ": ";
      br =document.createElement("br");
      ColorsAvailable.appendChild(p);
      ColorsAvailable.appendChild(color);
      ColorsAvailable.appendChild(br);
   }
}
```

```css
input[type='checkbox']
{
   margin-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the buttons to create a Checkbox.</p>

<button onclick="addCheckBox()">Create a button</button>
<input id="check" name="checkBoxes">

<div id="checkBoxes"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent!  A few little changes :)

The checkboxes appear on the same line and don't have the text visible (ie yellow, red, green) so they know what the checkboxes are for.... any advice

Comment: @Nadine Ok, I edited to show the labels. I also added a margin-right on the checkboxes for better readability.

Comment: @Nadine Did you want the checkboxes to appear one above of the other? If so it's an easy fix.

Comment: @ Ivan86  Thanks for that, and yes I did want them one above the other.

Comment: @ Ivan86.  Exactly what I was after.  Thanks

Comment: After every click its creating new checkbox, how to validate if checkbox are already there donot create new ???

Answer (score 1):

The id of the input was `check` and not `checkBoxes`. I changed it and also you can't directly append in the input so I made it append in the parent node but you could change to be on another place.

```html
<p>Click the buttons to create a Checkbox.</p>

<button onclick="addCheckBox()">Create a button</button>
<input id="checkBoxes" name="checkBoxes">
<script>
function addCheckBox() {

    var ColorsAvailable = document.getElementById('checkBoxes');
    var check_value = new Array( )
    check_value[0] = "Yellow"
    check_value[1] = "Red"
    check_value[2] = "Green"


   for(var count in check_value)
    {
      var color=document.createElement("input");   
      color.value=(check_value[count] + '</br>');
      color.type="checkbox";
      color.id="color" + count;
      ColorsAvailable.parentNode.appendChild(color);
   }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make checkboxes a DIV.

```
<div id="check" name="checkBoxes"></div>
```

and change this

```
var ColorsAvailable = document.getElementById('check');
```